# In python, how to have two classes share implementation of a method that calls another method with specific implementations for each class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

Suppose I have a parent class `Parent`, with abstract method `load` that is implemented in its childs classes. Now, I have two child classes `childA` and `childB`, both inheriting from `Parent`. The implementation of `load` for `childA` and `childB` identical. But this implementation of `load` calls another method, `get_paths`, that is specific to `childA` and `childB`. Parent is something like:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class Parent(ABC):
    def __init__(self, *params):
        # set up the params

    @abstractmethod
    def load(self, *params):
        # loads files, according to each children

    def process(self, *params):
        # process the loaded files
```

And then the children:

```py
class childA(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *paramsP, *paramsA):
        super().__init__(*paramsP)
        # Set up the specific paramsA

    def get_paths(self, *params):
        # specific implementation to childA

    def load(self, *params):
        # Calls the self.get_paths method, identical to childB.load
```

```py
class childB(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *paramsP, *paramsB):
        super().__init__(*paramsP)
        # Set up the specific paramsB

    def get_paths(self, *params):
        # specific implementation to childB

    def load(self, *params):
        # Calls the self.get_paths method, identical to childA.load
```

How can I reuse the code from `load` in both `childA` and `childB`, but have the `get_paths` implementation be specific to each class? I tried two approaches:

(1) Have `childB` inherit from `childA` instead, and override the implementation of `get_paths`. In this approach, I have:

```
class childB(childA):
    def __init__(self, *paramsP, *paramsB):
        super().__init__(*paramsP)
        # Set up the specific paramsB

    def get_paths(self, *params):
        # specific implementation to childB
```

I called it as:

````py
b = childB(...)
b.load(...)

However, when I call `childB.load`, the `get_paths` called inside of it is `childA.get_paths`. I noticed that because I was getting an error when running `b.load`, so tried putting a break point with `ipdb` inside of `childB.get_paths`, but execution did not stop. But when I put the breaking point inside of `childA.get_paths`, it did break.

(2) Implement another class, `AB`, with the following definition:

```python
class AB(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *paramsP):
        super().__init__(*paramsP)

    @abstract method
    def get_paths(self, *params):
        # To be implemented in childA and childB

    def load(self, *params):
        # Implements the load from childA and childB
````

and then have `childA` and `childB` both inherit from `AB` instead, and implement their specific `get_paths`. However, this did not work as well, as I get the error: `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ChildB with abstract methods _AB__get_paths`.

It is important to add I **cannot implement `load` in `Parent` because there are other classes ( `childC`, `childD`, ...) with unique `load` implementations.**. I just want to reuse this code between `childA` and `childB`

So, what is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: If `load()` is identical in both children, why not just put it on the parent class? And I assume this should be `class childB(Parent)` not `def childB(Parent)`?

Comment: There are other classes that inherit from `Parent` which have different implementations of load. Yeah, you are correct about the `def` being `class` instead (:

Comment: "Have childB inherit from childA instead, and override the implementation of get_paths. However, when I call childB.load, the get_paths called inside of it is childA.get_paths" um, it shouldn't be. Can you show your implementation and how you used it?

Comment: Updated the question with this description

Comment: So, I just found out the reason. I was missing the fact that the `get_paths` was being defined with `__`, so name mangling was causing all sorts of issues. I replaced the `_` by   `__´ and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want `Parent` to be inherited with abstract `.load`, just put implementation into `Parent`.

If `.load` is common only for this two childs – you can inherit from `Parent` with 3rd child like `LoadMixin` and inherit both `Parent` and mixin

---

One approach would be:

```
class LoadableChild(Parent):
    def load(self, *params): ...

class childA(LoadableChild):
    def get_paths(self, *params): ...

class childB(LoadableChild):
    def get_paths(self, *params): ...
```

Another is:

```
class LoadBase:
    def load(self, *params): ...

class childA(LoadBase, Parent):
    def get_paths(self, *params): ...

class childB(LoadBase, Parent):
    def get_paths(self, *params): ...
```

Note the order of inheritance in later approach, if you inherit parent as first superclass, there is no easy way around:

- if your mixin inherits `Parent` – there's no unambiguous MRO
- if mixin inherits `object` – there's instantiation error on abstract `.load`.

It's matter of preference, I'd say, for me personally first approach is cleaner

Comment: I did try the first approach, but because `load` uses `get_paths`, I need to define it as an abstract method in either `LoadableChild` or `Parent`, it is the (2) example in my question. I did that, but when I call `childB.load`, I get the error `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ChildB with abstract methods _LoadableChild__get_paths`,

Comment: There is no reason to define `load` as an abstract method just because it calls a function that you expect a child class to override.

Comment: Yeah, I added as abstract because the linter was complaining (: . But you are correct.